# How to optimize the repeated query?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have to make a query  with input date and end date. Here I have the same code repeated many times in the query.
In the example below only first db_A & db_b got only where condition different with start and end value to be same.

For db_C I dont have "where('a.compid', '9')" condition and start/end date is different.

Can anybody help me how can I optimize this code ?

This is the code I have tried.

```
$start = date("Y-m-01", strtotime($inputdate));
$end = $inputdate;

$db_A = DB::table('standard as a')
            ->join(DB::raw("(select distinct salid, cuscod, compid from stdmap_cus) b"), function($join){
                $join->on('a.compid', '=', 'b.compid')->on('a.cuscod', '=', 'b.cuscod');
            })
            ->select('b.salid', DB::raw('sum(turnover) as sumturn'))
            ->where('a.compid', '99999999')
            ->whereBetween('date', [$start, $end])
            ->groupBy('b.salid')
            ->get()->toArray();

$res_A = $this->getSalTurn(json_decode(json_encode($db_A), true));

$db_B = DB::table('standard as a')
            ->join(DB::raw("(select distinct salid, cuscod, compid from stdmap_cus) b"), function($join){
            $join->on('a.compid', '=', 'b.compid')->on('a.cuscod', '=', 'b.cuscod');
            })
            ->select('b.salid', DB::raw('sum(turnover) as sumturn'))
            ->where('a.compid', '!=', '99999999')
            ->whereBetween('date', [$startMTD, $endMTD])
            ->groupBy('b.salid')
            ->get()->toArray();

$res_B = $this->getSalTurn(json_decode(json_encode($db_B), true));

$start = date("Y-m-01", strtotime("-1 year", strtotime($inputdate)));
$end = date("Y-m-t", strtotime("-1 year", strtotime($inputdate)));


$db_C = DB::table('standard as a')
            ->join(DB::raw("(select distinct salid, cuscod, compid from stdmap_cus) b"), function($join){
                $join->on('a.compid', '=', 'b.compid')->on('a.cuscod', '=', 'b.cuscod');
            })
            ->select('b.salid', DB::raw('sum(turnover) as sumturn'))
            ->whereBetween('date', [$startMLY, $endMLY])
            ->groupBy('b.salid')
            ->get()->toArray();
$res_C = $this->getSalTurn(json_decode(json_encode($db_C), true));
```

Comment: If your goal is just to reduce the number of queries made on the database then you could simply not run `db_B` query and run the db_A query without `->where('a.compid', '99999999')` and then split the resultset into `==99999999` and `!=99999999` in the PHP code.

Comment: Take that to its natural progression and you could add a `orWhereBetween` to include the other date range and only run one query, then sort out the one resultset into 3 seperate datasets in your PHP code

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't understand your second comment. Can you give me example

Comment: Well I think you could do one query to replace all 3 if you used  `->whereBetween('date', [$startMTD, $endMTD])` and `->orWhereBetween('date', [$startMLY, $endMLY])` in the single query. Just more to sort out in the PHP code

Answer (score 1):

You can set default query, and then clone it.

```
$start = '...';
$end = '...';

$startMTD = '...';
$endMTD = '...';

$startMLY = '...';
$endMLY = '...';

$defaultQuery = DB::table('standard as a')
      ->join(DB::raw("(select distinct salid, cuscod, compid from stdmap_cus) b"), function($join){
          $join->on('a.compid', '=', 'b.compid')->on('a.cuscod', '=', 'b.cuscod');
      })
      ->select('b.salid', DB::raw('sum(turnover) as sumturn'))
      ->groupBy('b.salid');

$db_A = (clone $defaultQuery)
      ->where('a.compid', '99999999')
      ->whereBetween('date', [$start, $end])
      ->get();

$db_B = (clone $defaultQuery)
      ->where('a.compid', '99999999')
      ->whereBetween('date', [$startMTD, $endMTD])
      ->get();

$db_C = (clone $defaultQuery)
      ->whereBetween('date', [$startMLY, $endMLY])
      ->get();

$res_A = $this->getSalTurn($db_A->toArray();
$res_B = $this->getSalTurn($db_B->toArray();
$res_C = $this->getSalTurn($db_C->toArray());
```

And I think you don't need to use `json_decode(json_encode($db_A), true)`, it returns array that you already have.

Comment: Other than looking cool, this does not actually change anything or reduce the number of database queries, which I am assuming the OP is trying to do

Comment: @RiggsFolly >Here I have the same code repeated many >how can I optimize this code. He said nothing about query count and efficiency.